# tuple false indexing function that takes into consideration old false indices

Tags: python

Imagine a list of booleans, which are all True:

```
bools = [True] * 100
```

I then have a tuple that correspond to the index of the bool that i want to set to False:

```
false_index = (0,2,4)

for element in false_index:
    bools[element] = False
```

The next time i would like to set the False elements with the same tuple, the index of the false_index, needs to take into consideration the `False` values of the list that has already been flipped.

I would like a function that take the index of the values that are already flipped, and the new values to be flipped, and return a tuple of the true values to be flipped, like:

```
old_false_index = (0,2,4)
new_false_index = (0,2,4)
check_index(old_false_index, new_false_index) # output (1,5,7)
```

A more visual example:
for a list of 8 True values:

```
[
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
]
```

The first tuple changes the elements to False at the given indices. So for (0,2,4), the list has now been changed to:

```
[
1 # index 0
1 
1 # index 2
1
1 # index 4
1
1
1
]
```

The next time it is changed with the same tuple, the index has changed:

```
[
0
1 # index 1 but the first element that can be changed
0
1
0 
1 # index 5 but the third element that can be changed
1
1 # index 7 but the fourth element that can be changed
]
```

Comment: why `(1,5,7)` ?

Comment: If the first tuple represents originally flipped indices, then wouldn't this function just return the indices in the second tuple that are not in the first?

Comment: So i want the values that have been flipped to false to be "invisible". So that the length of the list of booleans are the sum. so if elements have already been flipped, the length is the 97

Comment: Unless you need to flip false values back to true to make them visible again, is something preventing you from just deleting the flipped elements of the list?

Comment: Are the tuples always sorted and have no duplicates?

Comment: Yes, always sorted and no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
def check_index(old_false_index, new_false_index):
    result = []
    for new_index in new_false_index:
        for old_index in old_false_index:
            # check if a smaller index already exists in the old
            # for each one you find, increment by one
            if old_index <= new_index:
                new_index += 1
        result.append(new_index)
    return tuple(result)

old_false_index = (0,2,4)
new_false_index = (0,2,4)
print(check_index(old_false_index, new_false_index)) # (1, 5, 7)
```

Keep in mind, if you're doing this repeatedly, you'll have to add the result to `old_false_index` in order to use `old_false_index` again in the same fashion.

```py
old_false_index = (0,2,4)
new_false_index = (0,2,4)
actual_new_false_indexes = check_index(old_false_index, new_false_index)
old_false_index += actual_new_false_indexes
```

Comment: @DHJ So there's no need to be efficient? (I.e., you don't have large lists/tuples?)

Comment: I do. Is there a faster approach?

Comment: Can I ask how large your largest expected `list` and `tuple` will be?

Comment: Not that big. Not more than 10000

Comment: Well, I should note, assuming `old_false_index + new_false_index` never exceed `len(bools)`, the time complexity for this is `O(n * k)`. The worst case I can think of for a `list` of `10000` bools is `25,000,000` iterations. Where you have two `tuple`s of length `5000`. If @KellyBundy provides a more efficient solution, feel free to switch the accepted answer.

Comment: @DHJ I suggest you put all that extra information into the questions There's much room for interesting and much more efficient solutions.

Comment: @Axe319 Note they commented that the tuples are always sorted, which both allows something faster and makes the `old_false_index += actual_new_false_indexes` incorrect (since that can make it unsorted).